# Snake Game random colors

Tags: javascript, random, colors

I created a snake game but i want every new block added onto it to genarate a random new color. This is what I have right now but all it does is send a "null" back and causes it to be white.

```html
// Draw a square for each segment of the snake's body
Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
this.segments[i].drawSquare(randomColor());
}
};








function randomColor() {
    return '#' + ('00000' + (Math.random() * 16777216 << 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which seems to work quite nicely from Dimitry K - http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

```
function randomColor() {
    var color = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2,8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
    return color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `randomColor` function work find, If something still wrong, let me know about your `Snake`
(and `segments` of `this`)

```
function randomColor() {
    return '#' + ('00000' + (Math.random() * 16777216 << 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
}
```